# New worker starting out

Tags: colleagues, new-job

I am straight out of uni and I recently started a new job as a web developer. Outside of my department, there are only about 5 people who actually believe I can help them with their questions face to face, despite the fact I have been helping most of the company through the helpdesk for months.

Whenever they come into my department looking for my manager when he is out, I offer to answer any questions and except for a few people, they always say they'll come back when my manager is here.

How do I get them to believe that I can actually help them despite my young age?

Comment: Sorry - are you a web developer, or IT helpdesk? Maybe they think you should be doing web development and not answering questions? And do you know what questions they have for your boss so that you know you can help them?

Comment: I am a web developer. I assist with help desk items that relate to the web

Comment: "For a few people, they always say they'll come back when my manager is here." - This may have nothing to do with their perception of your abilities or age. Sometimes you just need to talk with the manager for some things.

Comment: You are new, it has nothing to do with age.  Don't take it personally, people need to get used to you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't "get" them to believe anything - people are funny, and do things that only makes sense to themselves.

For example, they might not want to take you away from whatever you are doing without talking to your boss first (since he is your boss, and supposed to be in charge of your tasking). This is a good thing.

Eventually, as you keep working there, people will see what you do, and may talk to you direct (or your boss will simply tell them "Kylar can do that - ask him"). Until then, just keep doing what you can, and what your boss tells you to do.

Answer (score 2):

No one is going to believe what you say since no one knows you and you haven't built your reputation within the company. It will take time, it's not because you are straight from uni, it's because you haven't proven yourself.

Just keep working eventually your time to shine will come.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get them to believe that I can actually help them despite my
>   young age?

You ask your manager to communicate that you are his helper deputy in his absence. This typically involves an email to all parties saying "If I'm not available, X is capable of helping you."

While you may know that you are capable (and may have permission from your manager to help people), if that has not been communicated to everyone then they will likely not accept your help for fear of disrupting any plans that your manager may have for you.